# grep + when need to add backslash before dot character

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expression

Under the folder - `/var/my_private_pkgs`

We transferred packages that are split from ISO rhel 8.0

```
   rhel8.0aa
   rhel8.0ab
   rhel8.0ac
    .
    .
```

We are doing the following in order to verify the sum of packages in bytes

```
du -sb /var/my_private_pkgs/* | grep rhel8.0[a-z] 

419430400       rhel8.0aa
419430400       rhel8.0ab
419430400       rhel8.0ac
.
.
```

But I am not sure regarding to case above if we need to add the backslash before dot? in grep as the following

```
 du -sb /var/my_private_pkgs/* | grep rhel8\.0[a-z]
```

Dose both cases are ok? ,

Or maybe better to add backslash before dot?

Comment: here, you could probably also use `du -sb /var/my_private_pkgs/rhel8.0[a-z]*`, leaving it to the shell to filter the file names. Here, in the shell glob, the `.` is _not_ special, but the `[a-z]` works similarly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add backslash, when you want to match `.` !

In a regex, `.` is a special character meaning "any character".
It will e.g. also therefore match `rhel18x0a` which you might not want.

Btw, you should also qoute your pattern, as the shell will interpret your backslash, and effectively remove it before sending it to `grep`:

```
du -sb /var/my_private_pkgs/* | grep 'rhel8\.0[a-z]'
```